# how to disable all user interaction in UIWebView except scroll interaction

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I want to disable all user interaction in my `UIWebView`, only apply support of scrolling, because i only want to preview the webView. Is there have some good idea? Thanks.

Now I do as follows:

1.disable user interaction with my webView

2.add my scrollView ,and the frame is same as my webView

3.in `webViewDidFinishLoad`,i get content height of webView like this:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    [self defaultWebViewDidFinishLoad];
    [self.navigationItem setTitle:[self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"]];
    CGFloat height = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight"] floatValue];
    self.scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(DEVICE_WIDTH, height);
    self.webview.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(DEVICE_WIDTH, height);
}
```

4.when scroll my scrollView, set contentOffSet of my webView.Scrollview like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self.webview.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, scrollView.contentOffset.y)];
}
```

But there have a problem, many images cannot show when scrolling.

Comment: Could you please elaborate us your effort showing the necessary part of the code?

Comment: please, give the effect of answering any comment in the post itself by an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35471890/edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this delegate function:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

And return NO.

Comment: And I didn't test if first request will call this.If yes,you can return YES when the request is first one.

Comment: It works,thanks!
But have highlight when click,although it's a small problem.

Comment: It is good that this solution works for you but with this solution it will not load the new page/request all other functionality of webview like select/cut/copy/paste etc... will be still available

Comment: @Pyro If you want forbid any other interaction,I think the best solution is to make a fake view.Put web view on scrollView and make its user interaction NO.

Comment: it can't work. I mean like this http://www.cocoachina.com/bbs/read.php?tid=268097